# Merge maps and make values as array

Tags: java, arrays, collections

```
public class MapCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
        data.put("John", "Taxi Driver");
        data.put("Mark", "Professional Killer");
        Map<String, String> data1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        data1.put("John", "Driver");
        data1.put("Mark", "Murderer");
        Map<String, String> data3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        data3.putAll(data);
        data3.putAll(data1);
        System.out.println(data3);
    }
}
```

I have few maps which contains same key, their values are different. I want to merge them. But when I merge them with the usual `putAll()` it gives me only the value of the key which was inserted latest.

Output from above code is  `{John=Driver, Mark=Murderer}`

Is there a method which will get me all the values associated with the key and give me as a array like

```
{John=[Taxi Driver, Driver], Mark=[Professional Killer, Murderer]}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can produce a `Map<String, List<String>>` quite easily with Java 8 `Stream`s:

```
Map<String, List<String>>
    merged =
        Stream.of(data,data1) // create a Stream<Map<String,String> of all Maps
              .flatMap(map->map.entrySet().stream()) // map all the entries of all the
                                                     // Maps into a 
                                                     // Stream<Map.Entry<String,String>>
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, // group entries by key
                                             Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                                Collectors.toList())));
```

The output `Map`:

```
{John=[Taxi Driver, Driver], Mark=[Professional Killer, Murderer]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
void add(String key, String value, Map<String,List<String>> map) {
    List<String> list = map.get(key);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        map.put(key, list);
    }
    list.add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create `Map<String, <ArrayList<String>>`. That way you can store multiple values that are associated with one key.

You may consider creating method that provides storing multiple values associated to unique key in specified map:

```
public static void add(String key, String value, Map<String, List<String>> map) {
        // Here you create a refeREnce to instance of the list storing values associated with given key:
        List<String> listOfValues = map.get(key);
        // If given key was already present in the map...
        if(listOfValues != null) {
            // Add given value to list of values associated with given key:
            listOfValues.add(value);
        // If given key wasn't present in the map...
        } else {
            // Initialize an ArrayList that will store given value in the map:
            listOfValues = new ArrayList<>();
            // Put new entry into the given map (given key and to-be-filled list of values:
            map.put(key, listOfValues);
            // Put given value to the list of values associated with given key
            listOfValues.add(value);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the data structure `Multimap` may be the best choice. The implementation in guava is highly recommended.
https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Map<String, List<String>>` as a result works for you, here is an iterative version using [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) available since Java 8:

```
Map<String, List<String>> data3 = new HashMap<>();
for (Map<String, String> d : Arrays.asList(data, data1)) {
  for (String k : d.keySet()) {
    data3.computeIfAbsent(k, ignored -> new ArrayList<>()).add(d.get(k));
  }
}
```

Note: computeIfAbsent allows you to compute a value for a key if it's not already associated with a value. In this case, the mapping function passed to computeIfAbsent creates a new `ArrayList` if there is no existing value for the key `k`. Next, the value from `d.get(k)` is added to that list.